# Infinity norm for each row of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a numpy array:

```
t1 = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
```

I need to find the L-infinity norm of each row of the array and return the row index with the minimum L-infinity norm.

I am trying this to find the norm of each row:

```
rest1 = LA.norm(t1, ord='inf', axis=1)
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> raise ValueError(f"Invalid norm order '{ord}' for vectors")
> ValueError: Invalid norm order 'inf' for vectors

Can you all please suggest how I can do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
t1 = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
rest1 = np.linalg.norm(t1, ord=np.inf, axis=1)
# >>> array([ 3.,  7., 11.])
```